# Swift map and mapkit - add overlay and center it

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, overlay

I am learning how to use the SwiftUI and MapKit,
and I try to draw a MKCircle, it works except I'am unable to center the circle in the current map center

How to set center with MapView.centerCoordinate ?

```
        //HERE 
        let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D! = CLLocationCoordinate2D() 
        // How to set center with the map center (MapView.centerCoordinate) ?
```

---

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var circle: MKCircle?
    
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let mapViewDelegate = MapViewDelegate()
    var centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    func setupManager() {
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        
        setupManager()
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
        
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
        view.delegate = mapViewDelegate                                              
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false   
        addCircle(to: view)
    }
}

private extension MapView {
    
    func addCircle(to view: MKMapView) {
        if !view.overlays.isEmpty { view.removeOverlays(view.overlays) }

        guard let circle = circle else { return }

        
        //HERE 
        let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D! = CLLocationCoordinate2D() 
        // How to set center with the map center (MapView.centerCoordinate) ?
        
        
        let circle = MKCircle(center: center, radius: CLLocationDistance(1000))
        
        let mapRect = circle.boundingMapRect
        view.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10), animated: true)
        view.addOverlay(circle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should set your `mapViewDelegate` in `makeUIView` rather than `updateUIView` because `updateUIView` is called too many times, and you just need to set the delegate once.

Your issue comes from this line:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

It  means that when your map is instantiated, it will automatically focus on your  user's location.

```
func addCircle(to view: MKMapView) {

    // Lets put a defaut radius of 30 km
    let radius: Double = 30
    if !view.overlays.isEmpty { view.removeOverlays(view.overlays) }
    
    let aCircle = MKCircle(center: view.centerCoordinate, radius: radius * 1000)
    let mapRect = aCircle.boundingMapRect
    
    view.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50), animated: true)
    view.addOverlay(aCircle)
}
```

Then, in my `MKMapViewDelegate` `rendererFor`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    guard let circleOverlay = overlay as? MKCircle else {
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
    let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: circleOverlay)
    circleRenderer.fillColor = .blue
    circleRenderer.alpha = 0.1
    return circleRenderer
}
```